# Appropriate icon for score

Tags: icons, jquery

I'm designing a quizz with jQuery. It has 4 counters: "correct answer", "wrong answer", "timer" and "score". Each counter has a little icon describing the counter.

I have found good jQuery UI icons for all counters except "score". Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few ideas: a paper clipboard image (associated with someone writing down the score), a flip-over scoreboard, an abstract star/hexagon/shield, or a domain-specific reward (coin, treasure, heart, flower, horseshoe, etc.).

Comment: I went for the jQuery UI icon-ui-clipboard. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/22059/24/scores_icon) one [image]

Answer (score 5):

I'd consider using some kind of a star, maybe an 8+ point star so that it doesn't look like a some kind of a bonus counter.

[image]

I've also often seen coins and diamonds or some objects thematically related to the game used as score icons but that may not be possible in your case.

Answer (score 2):

How about a tally score type icon:
[image]